# Load shared library from subfolder in Git repository

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to load a global shared library using the @Library("xxx") annotation.
The "Retrieval method" in the global settings is set to "Git".
The library is located in a subfolder within the git repository, e.g.:

```
  my-library
     +-- src
          +-- com 
               + ...
```

When starting the build, jenkins loads the complete repository and looks for the "src" folder in the root directory. I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: Library xxx expected to contain at least one of src or vars directories"
```

However, I want Jenkins to use the library from the "my-library" subfolder